# PHP - Referencing an array value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This array is being populated with URL's using a for each loop (they are page number URL's)

```
$pageNumberLinks[] = "<a href= URL_code>".$page_number . "</a>";
```

I am trying to reference the $page_number variable value in each URL in the array as the foreach loop executes, so I can use an if statement to execute code based on the `$page_number` value. `$PageNumberLinks->page_number` is not working. Any advice?

```
foreach ($pageNumberLinks as $PageNumberLinks) {
    if ($PageNumberLinks->page_number == $z ) {
        // execute code
    } else {
        // execute code
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you define `$pageNumberLinks[$page_number] = "<a href= URL_code>".$page_number . "</a>";` ? This way, you will be able to loop through the indexes properly.

Comment: The `$page_number` variable isn't accessible in the way your are using it.  The `->` is attempting to access an object property.  Unless `$PageNumberLinks` is an object, then it won't work.

Comment: Good advice! The code works! But the foreach loop isn't displaying the URL's. It is only displaying numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$pageNumberLinks[$page_number] = "<a href= URL_code>".$page_number . "</a>";

foreach ($pageNumberLinks as $key => $val) {
    if ($key == $z) {
        // execute code
    } else {
        // execute code
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically what @fedorqui said 6 minutes ago in the comments?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yes, basically, except this is an answer not a comment.

Comment: Good advice! The code works! But the foreach loop isn't displaying the URL's. It is only displaying numbers.

Comment: @DeanOlsen: My foreach doesn't display anything.  That should be a trivial exercise depending on what you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your array with proper indexes which will make it easier for you to loop thru:

```
$pageNumberLinks[$page_number] = "<a href= URL_code>".$page_number . "</a>";
```

Then you create a loop like

```
foreach($pageNumberLinks as $pageNumber => $link){    
  if(  $pageNumber === $z ){
    //do code here
  }else{
   //do some code here
  }    
}
```